# After Database operations Ajax functionality does not works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here below my extrafieldscript.php

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'createField')
    {
        $fetch = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select MAX(id) from extrafields"));

        $id = $fetch[0] + 1;

        mysql_query("insert into extrafields (`id`,`active`,`type`,`name`) values ($id,0,1,'')");

        mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `mitglieder` ADD `adf$id` INT(11) NOT NULL");

        echo 'Inserted';

    }
```

And my script file is

```
function createField()
        {

            $.ajax({
                    url : 'extrafieldscript.php',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : 'action=createField',
                    success : function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        //location.reload();
                    }
                });
        }
```

My problem is - before database operation the alert is worked well. But after database page is reloads or nothing response in the page......

How to get "inserted" msg in my alert box after database operations....

advance thanks mates.

Answer (score 0):

The “Inserted” alert actually occurs **after** the database operation is performed. Ajax handler is called on successful ajax call.

Think of it as of callback (it is the callback.)

Comment: thanks, so i need to study what's callback...... Is there any other way to achieve my task??????

Comment: It depends on what your task is... The data is _likely_ inserted properly, since you got the “Inserted” message. So I guess the task is already achieved.

Comment: No mate. before db operation. I got that alert. but not in after db operation.

Comment: Please take a look at your database _carefully_ and see that inserts _were actually done_.

Comment: Now read what callback means and try to understand: alert is shown **after** DB operation.

Comment: k mate. thanks for ur suggestion. Do u know the correct callback syntax of my code.....